# How to link my nasm program to access argc?

Tags: assembly, gcc, linker, x86-64, nasm

Working on Linux, x86_64.

I'm learning assembly programming, and having a hard time finding appropriate documentation and discerning which documentation is applicable.

Using `nasm` as my assembler, and `ld` as my linker, I produced this program to exit the program with a code equal to the number of program arguments.

```bash
nasm -felf64 hello.s && ld hello.o && ./a.out "$@"
echo $?
```

```
section .text
   global _start
    
_start:
    mov rax, 60
    syscall
```

This is based on the idea that the syscall takes the exit code from `rdi`, and the `argc` value also seems to be placed in `rdi`, based on some experiments with Godbolt Compiler Explorer.

This doesn't work, always producing exit code `0`.

However, when I change `_start` to `main` and use `gcc` instead of `ld`, the program works.

```bash
nasm -felf64 hello.s && gcc -o a.out hello.o && ./a.out "$@"
echo $?
```

```
section .text
   global main
    
main:
    mov rax, 60
    syscall
```

This produces an exit code equal to the number of shell arguments.

After much trial and error and wandering Google, I was finally able to get this working, but my problem is that I don't know *why* it works. I'm really struggling to know which documentation I need to be reading. Currently I'm just trying everything I can find and piecing together the bits that work.

Comment: When using `main` and the C library, the program entry point is inside the C runtime which takes care of fetching the arguments and passing it to your `main` as per the calling convention. If you do not use the C library you get the arguments as per the OS convention, which means on the stack. Consult the _System V Application Binary Interface AMD64 Architecture Processor Supplement_ chapter _3.4.1 Initial Stack and Register State_

Comment: `main` is a normal function, which means it can be called, get parameters, returns a value, and returns to its caller, but `_start` is a "primitive" program entry point, which is not a function, so doesn't have to obey the standard function calling, parameter passing, and return valuing or returning to caller.  `_start` makes the transition from program entry to the normal calling convention, invoking `main` as a function and handling when/if `main` returns to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`main` is a function that takes `argc` as its first argument, so when `main` is entered, the value of `argc` will be in `rdi`, as you expected. `_start` is not a function, so registers and the stack will not be set up as they'd be if it were. According to the AMD64 System V ABI, `_start` will instead find `argc` on top of the stack (i.e., where the return address would be if it were a function). To make your program work with it, do `mov rdi, [rsp]` before `syscall` (it doesn't matter whether it's before or after `mov rax, 60`).

When you use `gcc` instead of `ld`, code for `_start` from glibc gets linked into your program that calls `main` with the standard function calling convention, which is why it works then.

Comment: Thanks for the concise explanation, this clears things up for me. I came across the System V ABI reference before coming to Stack Overflow, but I unfortunately didn't realize the connection to Linux (and hadn't heard of System V before). Is there a common/official reference I should be looking at to understand these core concepts about low-level programming in Linux?

Comment: @HymnsForDisco That ABI document is the official reference.

Comment: I mean more broadly that I didn't know I should be looking for "System V" until someone mentioned it here. I'm just wondering if there's any other informational starting point I've missed out on that would make this learning process less confusing.

Comment: @HymnsForDisco [The x86 tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) would be a good place to look.